Is there a way to duplicate a JSON based on a variable using JOLT?
So, I have an input that looks like this:
{
  "entityType" : "job",
  "id" : 1019167,
  "properties" : {
    "TemplateName" : [ "Development Bug" ],
    "CaseType" : [ "Internal project" ],
    "ProjectType" : [ "Development" ],
    "Team" : [ "" ],
    "Category" : [ "Bug" ],
    "WorkflowStepID" : [ "531" ],
    "ParentCaseID" : 1019167,
    "CaseName" : [ "Bug development - Test Title" ],
    "CaseWorkflow" : [ "Development Cycle" ],
    "Username" : [ "Huvxotup Telfiyi, Ewohuli" ],
    "CaseDescription" : [ "" ],
    "CustomerAccount" : "",
    "CustomerInstance" : "",
    "ParentTitle" : "Video test case",
    "Tag" : [ "development.regression.bug" ],
    "AssignedTo" : [ "" ],
    "TemplateDescription" : [ "Steps to reproduce: 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.  Current behavior: Expected behavior:  Squealers reports:" ],
    "Environment" : [ ],
    "ParentTeam" : "Framework"
  },
  "trigger" : "Xguehi Cuwo",
  "amountToCreate" : "3"
}

I am going to receive a number value in the "amountToCreate" variable. This is an example, as I'm not receiving this yet.
I am using currently this JOLT transformation for what I need before this:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "properties": { // prepare attributes
        "TemplateName|CaseType|ProjectType|Team|Category|WorkflowStepID|CaseName|CaseWorkflow|CaseDescription|Tag|AssignedTo|TemplateDescription|Username": {
          "*": {
            "@3,id": "main[&1].ParentCaseID",
            "@": "main[&1].&2",
            "@2,CustomerAccount": "main[&1].CustomerAccount",
            "@2,CustomerInstance": "main[&1].CustomerInstance",
            "@2,ParentTitle": "main[&1].ParentTitle",
            "@2,ParentTeam": "main[&1].ParentTeam"
          }
        },
        "Environment": { // prepare array elements
          "@": "arrays.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // in order to get non-arrays within the main array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "main": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "main": {
        "*": {
          "@2,arrays": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values from the "main" array
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I need to duplicate X times this JSON, based on the variable number that I will be receiving in the input, that can be 1 or 10.
Is there a way to do this duplication with JOLT?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I already have a JSON output for this existing transformation, which looks like this:
{
  "Environment" : [ ],
  "ParentCaseID" : 1019167,
  "TemplateName" : "Development Bug",
  "CustomerAccount" : "",
  "CustomerInstance" : "",
  "ParentTitle" : "Video test case",
  "ParentTeam" : "Framework",
  "CaseType" : "Internal project",
  "ProjectType" : "Development",
  "Team" : "",
  "Category" : "Bug",
  "WorkflowStepID" : "531",
  "CaseName" : "Bug development - Test Title",
  "CaseWorkflow" : "Development Cycle",
  "CaseDescription" : "",
  "Tag" : "development.regression.bug",
  "AssignedTo" : "",
  "TemplateDescription" : "Steps to reproduce: 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.  Current behavior: Expected behavior:  Squealers reports:",
  "Username" : "Huvxotup Telfiyi, Ewohuli",
  "CasesToCreate" : "2"
}

Is there a way to use a different JOLT transformation to take the "CasesToCreate" value and duplicate the JSON that many times?
Alternatively, I also have stored that value in an attribute in NiFi called "casesToCreate" thru an EvaluateJsonPath.
Can I use that variable in a JOLT transformation to duplicate the JSON?
I'm not sure if this is possible, but I've tried a lot of different approaches and nothing worked.
Again, thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.
EDIT v2:
This is the expected output, if it is possible:
{
  "Environment" : [ ],
  "ParentCaseID" : 1019167,
  "TemplateName" : "Development Bug",
  "CustomerAccount" : "",
  "CustomerInstance" : "",
  "ParentTitle" : "Video test case",
  "ParentTeam" : "Framework",
  "CaseType" : "Internal project",
  "ProjectType" : "Development",
  "Team" : "",
  "Category" : "Bug",
  "WorkflowStepID" : "531",
  "CaseName" : "Bug development - Test Title",
  "CaseWorkflow" : "Development Cycle",
  "CaseDescription" : "",
  "Tag" : "development.regression.bug",
  "AssignedTo" : "",
  "TemplateDescription" : "Steps to reproduce: 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.  Current behavior: Expected behavior:  Squealers reports:",
  "Username" : "Huvxotup Telfiyi, Ewohuli",
  "CasesToCreate" : "2"
},
{
  "Environment" : [ ],
  "ParentCaseID" : 1019167,
  "TemplateName" : "Development Bug",
  "CustomerAccount" : "",
  "CustomerInstance" : "",
  "ParentTitle" : "Video test case",
  "ParentTeam" : "Framework",
  "CaseType" : "Internal project",
  "ProjectType" : "Development",
  "Team" : "",
  "Category" : "Bug",
  "WorkflowStepID" : "531",
  "CaseName" : "Bug development - Test Title",
  "CaseWorkflow" : "Development Cycle",
  "CaseDescription" : "",
  "Tag" : "development.regression.bug",
  "AssignedTo" : "",
  "TemplateDescription" : "Steps to reproduce: 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.  Current behavior: Expected behavior:  Squealers reports:",
  "Username" : "Huvxotup Telfiyi, Ewohuli",
  "CasesToCreate" : "2"
}



what do you mean by "duplicate json"? what's the expected result?

Basically I need to duplicate the input I get. For example, the current transformation for this example gives me a JSON with one iteration for each array object.
I need that, for example if I receive a 3 in "amountToCreate", have 3 identical JSONs.

I took your last shift and transform it to bucket the json into a result field as follows:
...
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "main": {
        "*": {
          "@2,arrays": { "*": "[&1].result.&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values from the "main" array
          "*": "[&1].result.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }

Then I added the following Transformation to help with the duplication. It will use the number 10 in the leftPad function to generate 10 duplicates , but you can reference your flowfile attribute "CasesToCreate" in there to make it dynamic:
...,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "duplicateString": "=leftPad('1',10,'1')",
        "duplicateArray": "=split('',@(1,duplicateString))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "duplicateArray": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,result)": "[&]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

You can reference the flowfile attribute in the leftPad function as follows:
 "duplicateString": "=leftPad('1',${CasesToCreate},'1')"

Another option is to use the DuplicateFlowFile processor and then MergeRecord Processor which will give you the same result , however in the DuplicateFlowFile the value of the "Number of Copies" should be CasesToCreate-1.
Hope that helps
S
